# Commit() takes 50 seconds after inserting about 100000 rows

Tags: optimization, transaction, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that is, (I think), fairly small.

I has about 1 million rows in a couple of table and the total space on disk is about 150 Mb.

I then open a transaction and insert about 100000 rows, the time it takes is about 10 seconds and I think this is acceptable for that number of rows, (and given the fact that my app does some 'other' processing.

My concern is when I do the 'Commit()' itself.

It takes around 50 seconds to write the data to disk... (around 10Mb is actually written).

This is what I do:

```
-- pseudo code for brevity...
Data Source=database.db;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;

PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 16;
PRAGMA journal_size_limit = 1536;
PRAGMA cache_size = 10000;
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;

-- BEGIN TRANS

-- 100K Inserts/ 10K Deletes

-- COMMIT
```

Can anybody think why the commit would take so much longer than the entire transaction?

Any suggestions on how I could speed the commit up?

Answer (score 1):

In WAL mode, the database must do regular [checkpoints](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#checkpointing) to prevent the log from growing infinitely large.

So after a large amount of changes, it decides to do an [automatic checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#automatic_checkpoint) (especially since you have set `wal_autocheckpoint` to a rather small value).

You can move the checkpoint delay to another time (but not avoid it altogether) by doing checkpoints manually.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to change it to a larger amount, but it does not really make a difference to be honest.
The smaller amount was originally suggested by the Firefox performance wiki

Comment: The changes mades by your large transaction will exceed any reasonable limit. This is why I did not tell you to change that setting, but to do something else.